# How to clear TextInput on send button in React native with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-textinput

I am working on chat app using react native with redux, where messages are sending through the send button. But whenever I sent a message on hitting the send button, the `TextInput` is not clearing. 
I want to clear the `TextInput` field on hitting the send button. Here I am working in redux so I don't want to use `state` with `value`.

Here is the code :

```
class Chat extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchChat(this.props.receiverId);  
}

message(text) {
  this.props.writeMsg(text);    
}
onSend = () => {

  const { userId , receiverId, text } = this.props;
  this.props.sendMessage({userId , receiverId, text});
}

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

            <FlatList 
              inverted={-1}
              style={styles.list}
              extraData={this.props}
              data={this.props.convo}
              keyExtractor = {(item) => {
                return item.id;
              }}
              renderItem=   
              <ChatItem value={this.renderItem} />           
              />

             <MessageInput 
             onChangeText={text => this.message(text)}
             onPress={this.onSend }
            />          
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the component MessageInput's code:

```
  <View style={inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={inputs}
                placeholder="Write a message..."
                onChangeText={onChangeText}
              />
          </View>

            <TouchableOpacity style={btnSend} onPress={onPress }>
              <Icon
            name='send'
            type='MaterialIcons'
            color='#fff'
            style={iconSend}
            />  
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Hmm what's the benefit of not using state/value inside the MessageInput component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ref` to clear the value from `Chat`.

Add a new ref inside your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.textInput = React.createRef();
}
```

Pass the `ref` into `MessageInput`.

```
render() {
  ...
  <MessageInput 
    onChangeText={text => this.message(text)}
    onPress={this.onSend }
    ref={this.textInput}
  />
  ...  
}
```

Modify `MessageInput` (I am going to assume it's a functional component)

```
const MessageInput = (props, ref) => (
  ...
  <TextInput style={inputs}
    placeholder="Write a message..."
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    ref={ref}
  />
  ...
)
```

Finally, switch back to the `Chat` component and update `onSend`

```
onSend = () => {
  const { userId , receiverId, text } = this.props;
  this.props.sendMessage({userId , receiverId, text});
  this.textInput.current.clear(); // Clear the text input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with clearing the `text` property after the message is sended, (if the text property is what is rendered in the `TextInput`):

```
onSend = () => {

 const { userId , receiverId, text } = this.props;
 this.props.sendMessage({userId , receiverId, text});
 this.message('');
}
```

or

```
 onSend = () => {

  const { userId , receiverId, text } = this.props;
  this.props.sendMessage({userId , receiverId, text});
  this.props.writeMsg('');   
}
```